# flutter: operator '[]' isn't defined for the class 'Future<Map>'

Tags: flutter

I get this error when I try to access some data from a file

```dart
the operator '[]' isn't defined for the class 'Future<Map>'
```

How can I fix this?

```dart
Future<Map<dynamic, dynamic>> get getData async {
  final newData = await readFile().then((Map<dynamic, dynamic> value) {
    return value;
  });
  return newData;
}

final int time = getData['startTime']; // <--- error
```

Comment: final int time = await getData['startTime'];

Comment: thanks, but that didn't seem to fix it

Comment: `final int time = (await getData)['startTime'];` You should probably read about how Future and asynchronous programming works.

Comment: try `(await getData)['startTime']` or break it into two lines: `var myMap = await getData; final time = myMap['startTime'];`

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick!

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you're getting that error is because `getData` is a `Future`, not a `Map` - where `[]` can be used. As previously mentioned in the comments, the `getData` asynchronous function will only return a `Map` after `getData` is executed using the `await` keyword. You can read more details about asynchronous programming using Dart on this [guide](https://dart.dev/codelabs/async-await#execution-flow-with-async-and-await).